# Редирект с URL на ЧПУ

Tags: .htaccess

Доброе время суток
Не могу добиться результата, пытаюсь сделать редирект с

```
index.php?module=cabinet
```

на

```
/cabinet/
```

я написал рабочее правило:

```
RewriteRule ^cabinet/?$ /index.php?module=cabinet [L]
```

Но теперь выходит дубль, доступ к странице есть и с полного урл и с чпу
Нужно что бы был доступ только с ЧПУ, то есть сделать редирект

Заранее благодарен

Answer (score 1):

Вероятнее, будет правильно написать так:

```
   RewriteRule ^index\.php\?module=cabinet$ /cabinet/ [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteRule ^cabinet/([^/]*)(/?)+$ index.php?module=$1 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: результат странный весьма)

Comment: редиректит на http://site.com/D:/OpenServer/domains/site.com/index.php?module=